# Update a TIMESTAMP column to be nullable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that exists in two databases.

In one database there is a table with a column called `ROW_VERSION` that is of type `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL`.

In the second database the same table has the same column of type `TIMESTAMP` but it is of type `TIMESTAMP NULL`.

I would like to change the column in the first database to be nullable. This will allow me to synchronize between the two databases easier.

But when I run this:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable]
ALTER COLUMN ROW_VERSION TIMESTAMP NULL
```

I get the error:

> Cannot alter column 'ROW_VERSION' to be data type timestamp.

It is already a timestamp. **I just need to make it nullable. Is there anyway to do this?**

Comment: Is the column a primary key by any chance?

Comment: @DMason - No it is not.

Comment: If you switch out `timestamp` for `rowversion` in your tsql, will that work?  I believe the two datatypes are equivalent...timestamp is deprecated and somewhere down the line, it won't be in future versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer, the SO question you referenced is for MySQL.

Comment: @DMason - I get the same error message when I use `rowversion`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can.  And a table can only have one timestamp column.

You also cannot update a timestamp column, so the old "copy/drop/update" trick won't work.

You are likely stuck with what you have.

```
create table #tmp (id int, timestamp null)
insert into #tmp (id) values (1)
select * from #tmp


create table #tmp2 (id int)
insert into #tmp2 (id) values (1)
alter table #tmp2 add timestamp null
select * from #tmp2
```

I'm testing NULL TIMESTAMP columns, and it wont actually go NULL -- I can't find any documents stating it, but I don't think a NULL TIMESTAMP is possible (even if declared null, its never null in the data).

> timestamp is the synonym for the rowversion data type and is subject
>   to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use
>   rowversion instead of timestamp wherever possible. For more
>   information, see Data Type Synonyms (Transact-SQL)...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.110).aspx

Also...

> ALTER COLUMN Specifies that the named column is to be changed or
>   altered. The modified column cannot be any one of the following: A
>   column with a timestamp data type...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Alas, when I try to insert the ROW_VERSION to a different table, I get this error:  `Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.`

Comment: Yes, even if you add the column after the data is in the table, when you add the timestamp, it populates every row.  It definitely appears that column will NOT hold a NULL value.

Comment: @Vaccano, if you're just doing a merge from one box to another, I would just omit row_version from the column list and let the destination server handle the auto population of it.  You can also setup a merge to only update if the data has altered.  I tends to be faster to compare all columns than update all columns whether they need it or not.  If you want a sample, just say so and I'll add it.

Comment: I ended up researching and finding that since it was in my development environment, the timestamp column was not being used by any external or internal system.  Once I knew that, I was able to just delete the column and re-add it with the matching nullablilty.  Not sure why my Data Warehousing team went with a nullable timestamp column (because like you said, you can never insert null).  But as long as they match my compare tool can generate the script to upgrade the test database to match the dev one.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter a TIMESTAMP column (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)
You'll have to do the roundabout way of renaming the old table, creating a new table with the desired schema, inserting the data from the renamed table, then dropping that old table.  SSMS will probably script this for you if you change the column in the GUI.

> ALTER COLUMN
>   Specifies that the named column is to be changed or altered.
>
> The modified column cannot be any one of the following:
>
> •A column with a timestamp data type.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't do this.  It almost sounds like you'd want to use a date or datetime datatype for that column if you want it to be nullable.  I think of TIMESTAMP being analogous to the IDENTITY datatype in that they are both self-filling, auto-incrememting columns which don't really make sense to be null.  Also note that if you try the following:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#timestamptable') is not null 
    drop table #timestamptable
create table #timestamptable (id int, ts timestamp null)
insert into #timestamptable (id, ts)
values(1, null),
(2, null)
select *
from #timestamptable
```

Your timestamp column will still have data:

```
    id      ts
    1       0x000000004C8BED2B
    2       0x000000004C8BED2C
```

Comment: I don't care that they are nullable or not.  My DB Team put them there.  I need to do a merge from my dev env to my test env.  That merge script wants to drop and re-create the table because the nullability does not match.  What should be a very simple script is now very complex and risky.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Postgres SQL and the following works for me

```
`ALTER TABLE MYTABLE COLUMN MYROW DROP NOT NULL`
```

Answer (score -1):

FORCE THE TYPE
ALTER TABLE [MyTable]
ALTER COLUMN ROW_VERSION TIMESTAMP

remove indexes if exists

ALTER TABLE SOMETABLE DROP CONSTRAINT DF__SOME__index

maybe add with DEFAULT VALUE

ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD DEFAULT  0 FOR ROW_VERSION

I will just drop the table and recreate if allow it