# Is there a way to set a nullubule Timstamp2 back on null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

I have in a table a nullubule timestamp that tracks when the entry got called from a client. Sometimes something goes wrong on the client side and I need to set the timestamp back to null. I tried directly in SQL management studio to execute the query:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET [MyTimestamp]=null
WHERE ID=SomeInt;
```

I get the message that one row got altered but when I refresh my select * on the table there is no change on the timestamp.

PS: The whole DB runs on an azure server but I can also not get it to work on my test DB on local host in SQL Server 2014.

Would be grateful for input 

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms182776%28v=sql.120%29.aspx                                                          The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you [cannot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx) change the timestamp column to NULL. It is like a row version number.

Also

> The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time.

There are some workarounds which you can use as the one which is used here in the [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767446/update-a-timestamp-column-to-be-nullable) but now Timestamp datatype is rarely used.