# Alter column of type timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to update an empty table , which has a column of type timestamp to varbinary(8)

I used the following command

```
ALTER TABLE Notification  ALTER COLUMN RowRevisionID varbinary(8)
```

and I get and an error

> Cannot alter column 'RowRevisionID' because it is 'timestamp'.

How can I change a timestamp column type?

I do not wish to drop the column an add a new one , because that will create a column at the end , and I wish to preserve column order to use this table in an INSERT INTO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update a TIMESTAMP column to be nullable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767446/update-a-timestamp-column-to-be-nullable)

Comment: @JamesZ , I want to preserve the column orders because the table will be used in an INSERT INTO statement , and if I drop the column and add a new one the new one get added at the end of the table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You unfortunately cannot make a change to a timestamp column, as the error implies; you are stuck with what you have. Also, each table can only have one timestamp column, so you cannot duplicate the column in any solution.

Your best bet (depending on the size of the table) might be to copy the data into a staging table (using `SELECT * INTO MyTempTable FROM OriginalTable` syntax to preserve the timestamp values), then drop and recreate the original table with the desired columns in the desired order and reinsert the data, or you could add a new `VARBINARY(8)` column to the existing table and drop the timestamp column, preserving the original table. There are probably other solutions along the same lines as these, but all will require a new column, rather than an `ALTER COLUMN` script.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

`ALTER TABLE Notification DROP RowRevisionID;`

and

`ALTER TABLE Notification ADD RowRevisionID varbinary(8) AFTER myOtherColumn;`